# karma test, relead controller with different data set

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

I have a controller that I am writing tests for and the controller has a function that is run when the controller is loaded.  This function has an if statement that I want to test for both scenarios.  My problem is that the $scope I'm loading is only set for the "if" and not the else so I am not sure how to test the else.  I tried to set "skillList" to an array that would make the function go into the else portion but that doesn't work.  Is there a way to reload the controller when testing the "it"?

This is the function in my controller

```
  function loadIt() {
    if (!someService.skillList.length) {
      someService.getCategories().then(function(res) {
        someService.skillsLoaded = true;
       });
    } else {
       someService.skillcategories = someService.parseCategories(someService.skillList);
      someService.skillsLoaded = true;
    }
  }

  loadIt();
```

And in my test I have

```
beforeEach(function() {
  return inject(function($injector) {
      this.someService = {
      skillList: [],
      getCategories: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred.promise;
      },
      parseCategories: function(param) {
        return param;
      }
  };
```

So the test loads up skillList as an empty array which i have a test for that portion but I want to test the else where I need skillList to be [1, 2].  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass in the scope when you're creating your controller in the tests like this:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
scope.skillcategoriesList = ['list', 'goes', 'here'];

var controller = $controller('ControllerName', { $scope: scope });
```